# Django не может определиться с валидацией username

Tags: python, django

Суть: в Django 1.10 [завезли поддержку юникода в юзернеймах](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/1.10/#official-support-for-unicode-usernames).

Нюанс: она по умолчанию включена только для Python 3, а для Python 2 по-прежнему только ASCII.

Проблема: я пишу сайт для обоих питонах сразу (на 1.11; обновиться до 2.1, понятно, не могу) и периодически работаю то там, то тут. Когда я создаю миграцию в третьем питоне, джанга так и норовит создать бессмысленное изменение, меняющее валидатор на юникодный:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    # ...
    operations = [
        # ...
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='user',
            name='username',
            field=models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, unique=True, validators=[django.contrib.auth.validators.UnicodeUsernameValidator()], verbose_name='username'),
        ),
    ]
```

После применения этой миграции, если я создам новую миграцию уже во втором питоне — наоборот, джанга стремится всё откатить и вернуть ASCII обратно:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    # ...
    operations = [
        # ...
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='user',
            name='username',
            field=models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, unique=True, validators=[django.contrib.auth.validators.ASCIIUsernameValidator()], verbose_name='username'),
        ),
    ]
```

*(играем в игру «найди одно отличие» :)*

Я попытался явно прописать конкретный валидатор по образу и подобию [совета из документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.username_validator):

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.validators import ASCIIUsernameValidator

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class User(AbstractUser):
    username_validator = ASCIIUsernameValidator()
    # ...и всякие остальные поля
```

...но не изменилось абсолютно ничего: создание миграции в третьем питоне по-прежнему старательно пихает `UnicodeUsernameValidator` куда не надо, во втором питоне соответственно наоборот.

Как усмирить джангу и заставить использовать что-то одно на всех питонах, если совет из документации не работает?

Неужто копипастить поле `username` из исходников `AbstractUser` себе целиком? А поадекватнее способа не найдётся?

Comment: Интереса ради спрашиваю, а в чем проблема переписать на 3й питон все?

Comment: @MuckSon за два прошедших года уже переписал)) Но вообще до сих пор существуют хостинги, которые поддерживают только второй питон и не умеют третий, и я боюсь, как бы не пришлось на таких запускаться (но вроде не пришлось)

Comment: я так понимаю, что основная проблема в том, что бы при изменении БД  в дальнейшем у тебя не появлялось дополнительных "мусорных" миграций. Может просто смириться с этим поведением джанги, но в тексте миграции прописать разный код в зависимости от текущей версии питона?

Answer (score 1):

На ваш вопрос (что делать?) я не отвечу, но проиллюстрирую проблему простым примером:

```
class A:
    some_class_field = 'A field'
    swag_field_created_on_import_time = some_class_field

    def printer(self):
        print(self.swag_field_created_on_import_time)


class B(A):
    some_class_field = 'B field'

B().printer()
>>> A field
```

В исходниках происходит то же самое: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L308, только username_validators - это some_class_field, а сам username - это тоже классовый аттрибут, который создаётся во время импорта, и когда вы переопределяете этот аттрибут в своей кастомной модели, то это уже поздно полюбас - материнский класс создан, и все его классовые аттрибуты уже установлены

Как решение можно обмазываться метаклассами, который обновит свойство материнского класса из дочернего, или копипастить поле целиком